# Convert Crosstab to Sql Server Pivot

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access

I've been trying to do this conversion but kept denying me.

```
TRANSFORM (Nz(Sum(D.Loaded_Quantity),0)) AS Net_Quantity_Loaded
SELECT D.Dispatched_Date AS Date_Loaded, D.Product_Code, Count(D.Dispatched_Truck) AS
No_Of_Trucks_Loaded, Sum(D.Loaded_Quantity) AS Total_Quantity_Loaded
FROM Programme_Entry AS P INNER JOIN Dispatched_Entry AS D ON P.Meter_Ticket_ID =
D.Meter_Ticket_ID
WHERE (((D.Meter_Ticket_ID) Is Not Null))
GROUP BY D.Dispatched_Date, D.Product_Code
PIVOT P.Product_Destination;

VALUE from Product_Destination Column i.e. ([ABA], [BENIN], [CALABAR], [ENUGU]
, [GOMBE], [GUSAU], [IBADAN], [ILORIN], [JOS], [KADUNA], [KANO], [LAGOS], [MAIDUGURI]
, [MAKURDI], [MINNA], [MOSIMI], [ORE], [PHC], [SULEJA], [WARRI], [YOLA])
```

Thanks in anticipation for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to convert to?

Comment: @Brad An sql pivot table

Comment: an Oracle pivot, Sql Server pivot, MySql Pivot...?

Comment: @Brad Sql Server pivot